# When specifying local[n1,n2,n3] for spark master, what are the three parameters?

Tags: apache-spark

For launching spark, I have seen:

```
--master local[n1,n2,n3]
```

where n1, n2, and n3 are integers.

What do these refer to ?

Comment: where do you see that?

Comment: I can not find the original source at this point: maybe they had a typo  I CAN find this; "local-**cluster**[1,4,32000]")  for example  http://qnalist.com/questions/4848550/memory-configuration-in-local-mode

Comment: Ah, yes, it must be `local-cluster`! I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The master specification is parsed in [SparkContext.createTaskScheduler](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2107). (See the link for the implementation.) The possibilities with `local` are:

- `local` uses 1 thread.
- `local[N]` uses N threads.
- `local[*]` uses as many threads as there are cores.
- `local[N, M]` and `local[*, M]` are like above, but set the maximal task failures to M. This allows you to enable retries when running locally. (Normally local retries are disabled. Enabling them is useful for testing.)
- `local-cluster[numSlaves, coresPerSlave, memoryPerSlave]` starts executors in separate processes as configured, but it does not require running workers and masters. It's a lightweight way to simulate a cluster in unit tests. (See also [SPARK-595](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-595).)

Answer (score 4):

only these parameters are supported for "local" master mode :

- local : one thread
- local[n] : n threads
- local[*] : as much thread as possible considering your CPUs

c.f. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Regards,

Olivier.