# Use library in Spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use [this](https://github.com/tbsalling/aismessages) library in spark-shell and/or in a .scala file to manipulate some data. How do I do that? I cannot use maven.

EDIT for possible dupl: I also do not have a jar; if that is part of the solution, how do I make a jar from that library?

Comment: The project itself is built using maven. You either download the source code and build it or download the jar directly from Maven Central: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dk.tbsalling/aismessages. If you click on a specific version, there is a "Download Jar" link.

Comment: @Matt - this question is not a duplicate of the one you linked, and does have a specific answer which is not showing up anywhere near the top of a Stack Overflow search. See my answer.

Comment: @Yawar fair enough, I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The library you reference is available on Maven Central, and `spark-shell` can automatically download libraries from Maven Central and a few other popular repositories if you give it the correct Maven coordinates. You don't need to explicitly use Maven. (In fact, it even lets you specify your own additional Maven repositories and searches those as well.) See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#using-the-shell

In your case specifically, the command should be something like

```
./bin/spark-shell --master local[4] --packages "dk.tbsalling:aismessages:2.2.1"
```

> Note: You can browse https://spark-packages.org/ to find spark
>   packages.

Comment: Thanks! I already accepted your answer but to make sure I understand it correctly, you specify `--master` to show which is the master node? Isn't the node from which the shell is started the master by default? Also, about `local[4]`. I googled a bit and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995938/when-specifying-localn1-n2-n3-for-spark-master-what-are-the-three-parameters . Isn't `local[*]` always more appropriate? Or is there a good reason why you would specify 4, in this case?

Comment: @Dimebag - the `--master whatever` argument isn't really important, you should use whatever you were already using :-) the critical thing here is the `--packages "groupId:artifactId:versionId"` argument.

Comment: Does this install the library to your local spark so that it does not need to be done again every time? If not how to get that library installed locally?